# Laravel View Composers Setting Cookie

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-4

I have a weird issue, I can't set any cookies in my view composer.

**Background:** We have our own (not the server I am working) OAuth 2 server using **refresh** and **access** tokens. Basic flow goes, user clicks login, I send a HTTP Request to server getting a login url and redirect the user there. From there he logs in and gets returned to me with an access token and refresh token. I get his details using the access token, set a user, access token and refresh token cookie and life goes on.

**Actual Problem:** Now the user or access token cookie expires (I just delete it in my browser), I go get the access token if it is available (it is for the test and it is valid). I then get a new access and refresh token, get the user details again as well and try to save those details (like previously done) in cookies. Except it never seems to get there.

**The Code:** Obviously there is a lot of code involved and I can't post it all, but the crux of the problem with be in my [view composer](http://pastebin.com/Y6R1z4g7). I have tried many ways of setting the cookie, from redirecting to making views in both Chrome and Firefox extensively and check if exists in my code and in my browser.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: PS: I var_dump'd the Response Object, the cookies are there...

Answer (score 1):

So, queue...

`Cookie::queue("access_token", $refreshResults["access_token"], 60);`

As far as I can understand (and I am probably wrong) the view passed to the view composer doesn't add the cookies that was attached to it to the Response class. Changed all my cookie setting to queuing and it worked!

PS: If anyone wants to over an explanation or another answer, please do, I would really appreciate a better or more correct understanding.